# Ignore a null statement, apply method only to strings that are populated

Tags: c#, string, exception, methods, null

How do you ignore a null statement, and only apply a method to remove special characters to only strings that are populated.

```
Answer1 = RemoveSpecialChars(doc.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Answer[@answerid='1']").Attributes["keypress"].Value);                 
Answer2 = RemoveSpecialChars(doc.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Answer[@answerid='2']").Attributes["keypress"].Value);

 public string RemoveSpecialChars(string input)
       {

           return Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\._]", string.Empty);
       }
```

What's happening, is when the user presses and sends an answer one, and nothing for answer two I get an exception, because the method is trying to run on an empty string.  What is the best way to pass answer1, if answer 2 is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is not in the `RemoveSpecialChars` method, but rather in the return value of `SelectSingleNode` (which may be `null`) or the `Attributes["keypress"]` attribute (which may also be `null`).

Any of the above will result in a `NullReferenceException`. Here's rewritten code to guard against the first, which is probably causing the issue:

```
var node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Answer[@answerid='1']");
var node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Answer[@answerid='2']");

Answer1 = node1 == null ? null : RemoveSpecialChars(node1.Attributes["keypress"].Value);
Answer2 = node2 == null ? null : RemoveSpecialChars(node2.Attributes["keypress"].Value);
```

**Update**:

To guard against a null `keypress` attribute, you would do

```
Answer1 = node1 == null || node1.Attributes["keypress"] == null
            ? null 
            : RemoveSpecialChars(node1.Attributes["keypress"].Value);
```

and the same for `Answer2`.

Comment: the answerid will always be there, it is the keypress that is sometimes empty.  The exception comes from running that method on an empty string, in this case answerid2= 2, but keypress2="", would your proposed way be the same?